# Bluetooth on 2.0+

Tags: android

I'm doing bluetooth development for connecting with a PC. I've basicly used the BTChatExample and changed the UUID to the standard PC SPP-profile.

1. Trying to close a bluetooth application during a blocking read, by closing the BluetoothSocket will leave the Bluetooth stack in a unusable state. This can only be fixed by disabling and enabling bluetooth and restarting the application. Checking logcat, you can see that some of the internal methods are failing, leaving a open port. Any information on this?
2. First of all there seams to be differences on how bluetooth is implemented on N1 and HTC Legend/Desire both running 2.1, do you know anything about this?
3. Connecting isn't 100% reliable, sometimes I get a warning saying `~PortSystemContext init: FAILED`. This leaves bluetooth unusable, and restarting is needed.
4. Am I right in assuming that SPP is the only profile supported for use with the APIs? That's what the docs on the BluetoothAdapter says.

I would love to discuss issues on bluetooth with a developer and iron out these bugs so that Android can have good proper Bluetooth support it deserves.

Answer (score 2):

Closing a socket in one thread during a blocking read should definitely cause the read to return (by throwing IOException) and should not leave the stack in a 'bad state'. This is the behavior on Droid and Nexus.

I spoke directly to the original poster, and he had observed this problem on HTC Legend and HTC Desire. It appears like they are not implementing the API's correctly. I am raising the issue with them.

You are correct that SPP/RFCOMM is the only profile that is intended for use with the API's. SPP/RFCOMM gets you a streaming socket which is good enough for a lot of use cases.

For now I recommend BT development on Nexus One / Motorola Droid, which are considered 'reference' implementations of the Bluetooth API's.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you do not perform blocking `read()` calls unless you have first checked that there is data ready to be read by using `inputstream.available()` which returns an integer indicating how many bytes are waiting in the input buffer.

```
    long timeouttime = gettimeinseconds() + 2;
    String response = "";

    while (gettimeinseconds() < timeouttime) {
      if (inputstream.available() > 0)
          response = response + inputstream.read();
      } else {
          Thread.sleep(100); // sleep to slow down the while() loop. 
      }
    }
return response;
```

That's just pseudo code, and its oversimplified. The bottom line is that we're not performing any blocking calls (`read()`) unless we're sure they will return immediately without delay.

Also, I highly recommend using `BufferedInputStream` instead of the standard `InputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone could solve this problem ?

I try the following code :

```
// Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
while (!isInterrupted)
{
    try
    {
        //Clear buffer
        buffer = new byte[1024];

        // Read from the InputStream
        if (mmInStream != null && mmInStream.available() > 0)
        {
            if (isInterrupted)
                break;

            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(Act_Main.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    this.wait(100);
                }

                if (isInterrupted)
                    break;
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "WAIT_EXCEPTION:"+ ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", ex);
        connectionLost();
        break;
    }
}
```

And I changed the `isInterrupted` boolean in the `cancel()` method. Here is my `stop()` method:

```
/**
 * Stop all threads
 */
public synchronized void stop()
{
    isStop = true ;

    if (D)
        Log.d(TAG, "stop");

    if(mConnectThread != null)
    {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if(mConnectedThread != null)
    {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    setState(STATE_NONE);
}
```